# Api Gateway deploy with Kong and Nginx

Tags: nginx, api-gateway, kong

I have this problem with Kong Api Gateway--
after all configureation and testings--
I am able to succesfully do this operation:

> `curl -i -X GET   --url http://localhost:8000   --header 'Host: api.saviourgidi.com'`

I got this json response back `{"hello": "test"}` Indicating this is working well.

--now i want to deploy it to production where clients would not use curl or httpie--

Can I deploy it with nginx and how?

````
>```
{
  // how do I translate this curl command to nginx so that nginx would serve the api.
}
````

Answer (score 0):

Kong is **built on** NGINX so you don't have to deploy it with NGINX. :)

Are you asking about how to use a load balancer in front of Kong?

Comment: What I really want to achieve was to proxy request without having to specified a header -Host. But I found the `path` route in the documentation which would direct traffic upstream.

Comment: You could also try removing the undesirable header with request transformer plugin (https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/request-transformer/) before the request reachs the upstream with the config.remove.headers=<NameOfYourBadHeaderHere> option